# Ruby on Rails Migration/model delete

Tags: ruby, database, migration, reset, ruby-on-rails-5

Yep fail... I messed things up how do I kill a model and migration so I can start it all over. I tried to get it to work with `db:drop` `db:create` `db:migrate` `db:reset`... can I just delete the model file and create a new one nothing seems to work.

Rails 5b3 ruby 2.3

Comment: And the question is?

Comment: and the question is answered below. rails d model "model name"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way I follow to delete a model is, first run:

```
rake db:migrate:status
```

and if you are on rails 5 I think the command would be:

```
rails db:migrate:status
```

So this will show the status of your migration. If the migration is `up` then run:

```
rails db:migrate:down VERSION=version_no
```

or

```
rake db:migrate:down VERSION=version_no
```

Then you can safely destroy the model:

```
rails d model ModelName
```

So this will safely delete your model and migration files.

Hope this helps.